# How to use indeterminate progress bar in appcompat-v7 r21 library?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-progressbar, material-design

Using the new r21 appcompat library, I wanted to show an indeterminate (spinning) progress bar in the Toolbar.

Previously, using the < r21 appcompat library, it worked, but it seems that there is no implementation of the progress bar in r21. Am I right? Is there a way for this without creating a custom progress bar?

My onCreate method starts with:

```
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: 1) The latest AppCompat is r22. 2) I am guessing you are using Eclipse, consider upgrading to Android Studio/Intellij. 3) Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no, you have to create a custom progress bar in your Toolbar. Progress is not supported in action bars for 21+